# perform realm migration for multiple .realm files

Tags: objective-c, realm, realm-migration

i have multiple realm files, (one per user logged into my app) and i need to run a migration for each realm file in the file system

```
      RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

  config.schemaVersion = 1;
  config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
    //do the same changes for all file.realm in the filesystem 
    }
  };


  [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];

  [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

how can perform a realm migration for each of the filesystem databases and not only for the default realm file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`+[RLMRealm migrateRealm:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/migrateRealm:) performs the migration for the Realm at the path specified by the configuration:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.schemaVersion = 1;
config.migrationBlock = ...;
config.path = @"path 1";
[RLMRealm migrateRealm:config];
config.path = @"path 2";
[RLMRealm migrateRealm:config];
```

Comment: config.path = @"path 1"; must be the name of the .realm file? or a nsurl to the realm file, thanks for this answer!

Comment: path is the string path to the realm file. the same value given by `-[RLMRealm path]`.

Comment: This maybe will come in handy as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828851/migrating-multiple-realms-realm-version-greater-than-schema-version-exception/33828852#33828852