# Realm equivalent of setDefaultConfiguration:config for other realms

Tags: ios, realm

What is the best practices for setting up configs and storing them on realms other than the default. With a migration, you get the default config, alter it for the different realm, and perform the migration. How do you set this new altered config as the "defaultConfiguration" for that specific realm and not the default realm? Or, as I hope not, do I have to repeat my configuration setup, including schema version number and path when I access my realm using `RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config:error:`?

(I'm using Objective C for this project, but it's come up in Swift projects as well).

Is this a shared instance scenario? Is this a just do it twice scenario?

This question doesn't really cover how to "store" that new config information but is illustrating my point.
[perform realm migration for multiple .realm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957225/perform-realm-migration-for-multiple-realm-files)

Answer (score 0):

The configuration object is how Realm identifies what file to open, so you inherently have to pass one in when opening a Realm other than the default one. Normally you will want to store the `RLMRealmConfiguration` object for each file rather than just storing the path (it's a plain-old NSObject that can be passed between threads).

Comment: Store it how? Right now I'm just recreating a singleton at app load and setting schemaVersions and migration blocks at that time then referencing that singleton whenever I access the realm.